# Interdimensional redstone circuitry in tekkit-lite?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building a gigantic horizontal quarry consisting of more than 5000 redstone tube frames and block breakers, all this in a mystcraft dimension. I used to remotely control the bc quarries i have there using redstone energy cells, but how am i going to control (temporarily turn off) this monster from the overworld? Is there any possibility of interdimensional redstone signal exchange in tekkit-lite? Or any 1.4.7 mod i could add to achieve this?

This is the monster. [image]

Btw. this eats an extreme amount of RAM when activated, it should probably be smaller.

Comment: I presume you use a chunkloader to keep it loaded while you are in the overworld? I would just make that remote.

Comment: Assuming its chunk loaded this could be done with Computer Craft and Ender Chests (and possibly openccsensors if 1.4.7 is to old for required computer craft methods) which I believe are all in the tekkit-lite pack... Having an item in a certain slot of the chest triggers a redstone signal from a turtle/computer. The chest can be accessed from other dimensions (or a pouch can act like a remote)

Comment: Sounds good @ computercraft. About making the chunkloader remote: What? Does that even work, and how?

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstaning... I cant imagine the functionality of remotely turning on a chunk loader, if its not loaded its not really there to be turned on...

Comment: I thought so, but then i don't understand Flaunting's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking an Ender Chest inventory is one way to go...

Wireless redstone offers a better solution:

Wireless [Transmitter](http://tekkitclassic.wikia.com/wiki/Wireless_Transmitter)/[Remote](http://tekkitclassic.wikia.com/wiki/Wireless_Remote) and [Receiver](http://tekkitclassic.wikia.com/wiki/Wireless_Receiver)

- I tested and they work across dimensions

[image]

Comment: really these work across dimensions? That's almost too easy :-P

Comment: @kutschkem why not try and find out?

Comment: @BakedPotato Tried it, i confirm it works.