# How can i improve the performance of redpower frame tubes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, performance, minecraft-redpower

Now that [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181411/interdimensional-redstone-circuitry-in-tekkit-lite) was answered and my horizontal redpower quarry is working, i feel it needs improvement because whenever i turn the switch for the 5000+ block breakers, two things happen:

- a delay of several seconds before the signal actually switches and all the blocks are broken
- several minutes where minecraft struggles with all the items flowing through the tubes, symptoms are console messages "memory connection overburdened" and, for example, my recycler working at a slower rate because, i guess, creation of new items is forbidden or something. Also all interactions (looking into a chest etc. take several seconds.

Now the first point is not so problematic, but the second point pretty much stalls my game until (? i don't even know, i guess when enough items have left the system)

How can i improve this, what is the cause for these problems? I can think of ways to make the pathfinding for the items easier, but is that any problem at all here?

Comment: That's like saying (in real life, not minecraft) "here, 50 watermelons instead of 1! Now bring them over there and please do it in the same time as you usually do!" Some parts in the chain(Java, CPU, GPU, render queue, whatever) are just plain overloaded by 5k+ items. The only way to solve this is by reducing the amount of items you cause. Seriously 5k items is enough to bring quite some servers/pc's to their knees for a bit.

Comment: Ok granted, but what part is overburdened? Is this rendering, the existence of those items outside of containers, the pathfinding through the frames? If it's rendering, why does it happen when i am in a different dimension. Anyway, i think this question has an answer but depends on what is really the problem. I will experiment tonight with redstone repeaters and multiple destinations to spread out the load over time a bit.

Comment: Items are entitities, when these are loaded, they get a check every tick to see if something needs to be done (despawn timer decreased/moved/deleted/picked up/anything/nothing), and this takes some time. So probably more CPU/java thread(or RAM, no clue really, but you excluded GPU) being overloaded then anything else. If you unload the chunks with these item masses in them, the lag'll stop. And I remember pipes with loads of items causing even more lag (pathing algorithm stuff, might be improved in later versions)

Comment: @Arperum but a block breaker quarry doesn't spawn the items as entities at all, it's just a custom rendering trick of the tubes

Comment: Those pipes have to do their ticking operation anyway, to calculate *where* exacxtly each item is in them, so it's gonna cause a hit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

each time the block breakers get a signal each of them needs to break the block in front of them and path to the nearest available inventory (cause of the initial lag)

after that it needs to render all the items in the tubes as they travel, that causes overhead because each of the pipes is a tile entity that needs to send a representation of the items traveling to it to each player in rendering range each tick.

the first step can be made bearable by staggering the block breakers' activation and decreasing the search space. every few rows separate the tubes in the frames with a panel and add a delay to the next segment, provide each section with its own enderchest.

If you still want only a single output then you should use a regulator with a stack of cobble in the output filter, or simply void it with a filter before the output at several points